# Multicast messages not processed

Tags: java

i have the following data flow on my interface:

> 08:52:45.777966 IP CICO.5120 > 224.7.7.254.5701: UDP, length 30
>
> 08:52:45.778293 IP CICO.5120 > 224.7.7.254.5701: UDP, length 27
>
> 08:52:46.176872 IP CICO.5120 > 224.7.7.254.5701: UDP, length 30

i wrote a java class that supposed to receive and elaborate that packets, here a cut of the class:

```
DatagramPacket rxPachet = new DatagramPacket(buff, buff.length);
try {
    String group = "224.7.7.254";
    MulticastSocket udpSocket = new MulticastSocket(5701);
    udpSocket.joinGroup(InetAddress.getByName(group));
    while (true) {
        new ShowMessage("....inside.....");
        try {
            udpSocket.receive(rxPachet);
            buff = rxPachet.getData();
            // SOME OTHER STUFF......
```

but when i run my application i don't see any packet processed.

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled blocking these packets? Is your network setup to allow multi-cast?

Answer (score -1):

i think i figured out the problem, here the new cut of the class:

```
MulticastSocket udpSocket = new MulticastSocket(5701);
udpSocket.joinGroup(new InetSocketAddress("224.7.7.254", 5701), NetworkInterface.getByName("vmnet2"));
```

one more thing, i had to add the option -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true if running on mac, otherwise i get exception "Cannot open multicast socket".
thanks to everyone.